# How to replace plain text contents or text nodes after group of span elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to replace every comma immediately after the `<span class="inf-group">...</span>` node with vertical bars because I have no access to the original html directly. I've even made a mistake, editing the part using css pesudo-element like `::after`. Is there any javascript or jQuery solution to operate on the whole isolated text nodes?

Sample representation as it is:

```html
<span class="irreg-infls">
    <span class="inf-group"><span class="inf">aaa</span></span>
    ,
    <span class="inf-group"><span class="inf">bbb</span></span>
    ,
    <span class="inf-group"><span class="inf">ccc</span></span>
</span>
```

Final representation for users:

```html
<span class="irreg-infls">
    <span class="inf-group"><span class="inf">aaa</span></span>
    |
    <span class="inf-group"><span class="inf">bbb</span></span>
    |
    <span class="inf-group"><span class="inf">ccc</span></span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following code to replace the same.

See [Check node type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)

```js
document.querySelector('.irreg-infls').childNodes.forEach((node)=>{
    if(node.nodeType == 3 && node.nodeValue.trim() == ',' ) {
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(',', '|');
    }
})
```

```html
<span class="irreg-infls">
    <span class="inf-group"><span class="inf">aaa</span></span>
    ,
    <span class="inf-group"><span class="inf">bbb</span></span>
    ,
    <span class="inf-group"><span class="inf">ccc</span></span>
</span>
```

Comment: When you're using code snippet, make sure it's a working one.

Comment: I will make it sure form next time. Thanks for guidance @SagarV

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nextSibling` with `textContent` like:

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.inf-group');
divs.forEach((div,index, array) =>{
  if (index !== array.length - 1){ 
    div.nextSibling.textContent = div.nextSibling.textContent.replace(',','|');
  }
});
```

```html
<span class="irreg-infls">
    <span class="inf-group"><span class="inf">aaa</span></span>
    ,
    <span class="inf-group"><span class="inf">bbb</span></span>
    ,
    <span class="inf-group"><span class="inf">ccc</span></span>
</span>
```

To get the exact result I excluded the last one element

Comment: Replace only `,` and maintain the spacing. Use `String.replace`

Comment: Besides handling the last one by index, `document.querySelectorAll('.inf-group:not(:last-of-type))` will get the same result on my local code.